# Generic constraint so that all properties in T must be the same type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function which, given an object that contains exclusively properties of a certain type, returns another object with the exact same keys, but all properties have a different type from the original.

Here is what I have tried:

```js
export type SettingsArgType = { [key: string]: { default: boolean, name: string, desc: string } };
export type SettingsReturnType<T extends SettingsArgType> = {
    [key in keyof T]: boolean;
};
export async function settingsHelper<T extends SettingsArgType>(options: T): Promise<SettingsReturnType<T>> {
    var ret: Partial<SettingsReturnType<T>> = {};
    // Irrelevant stuff here
    return ret;
}
```

Basically I'm trying to transform `{ [key: string]: { default: boolean, name: string, desc: string } }` to `{ [key: string]: boolean }`, and the keys should always be the same between the two. I've tried a couple of things, but when I try to call this function the `SettingsArgType` constraint is not enforced the way I would like.

Comment: `ret: Partial<SettingsReturnType<T>>`?

Comment: Thanks for that. That solves one of my problems.

Comment: "constraint is not enforced the way I would like." How would you like it to be enforced? When I [try your code](https://tsplay.dev/wgKKyw), I think I get the result you describe. Please [edit] your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the a real type you are starting with, the type you want to get as output, and the type you are getting instead.

Comment: It works fine in practice, but nothing is stopping you from not following the `SettingsArgType` type. I would like that to not happen. At least this is what my editor is telling me.

Comment: _"but nothing is stopping you from not following the SettingsArgType type"_ What type is it allowing that you do not want? If you pass in `{ missingProps: { bad: true } }` then you get an error as expected, so you must be worried about _extra_ properties like `{ default: true, name: 'derp', desc: 'Derpy!', extra: true }`? If this assumption is correct, then does [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/Wvyy4m) meet your needs? If so I can write that up as an answer. If not, what am I misunderstanding here. And please [edit] your question with _specifics_ about what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

`T extends SettingsArgType` means that `T` must fulfill the contract of `SettingsArgType`, not that it must be *exactly* that type.

And then `{ [key: string]: { default: boolean, name: string, desc: string } }` describes an object type where every key is an object with those three properties.

So then, a type like this fulfills that contract:

```
{
  [key: string]: {
    default: boolean,
    name: string,
    desc: string,
    extra: boolean, // added
  }
}
```

Typescript knows that the required properties are there, so you could say that type `T` *extends* that inner type. Extra properties are allowed on `T` because you may actually *want* to propagate those properties through to the return type somehow.

---

To prevent this, you don't want a type that `extends` this object type. You simply want this object type. They only generic type parameter you care about here are the keys of the object.

Which means you can change your function to this:

```
export async function settingsHelper<K extends string>(
    options: Record<K, {
        default: boolean,
        name: string,
        desc: string,
    }>
): Promise<Record<K, boolean>> {
    var ret: Partial<Record<K, boolean>> = {};
    // @ts-expect-error Irrelevant stuff here
    return ret;
}
```

Now generic type parameter reads `K extends string` meaning that to only dynamic bit we want is a union of strings, which is the keys of outer object type.

And with `K` we can expect a `Record` type where the only allowed keys are `K` and all values must match the inner object type.

And we can use `K` again in the return type with:

```
Record<K, boolean>
```

This now works like, I believe, you expect:

```
const testGood = await settingsHelper({
  derp: { default: true, name: 'derp', desc: 'Derpy!' }
}) // fine

const testBad1 = await settingsHelper({
  missingProps: { bad: true }
}) // type error

const testBad2 = await settingsHelper({
  derp: { default: true, name: 'derp', desc: 'Derpy!', extra: true }
}) // type error
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwM4E8B2BjOAzArpmASwjTiWBiLQHMkAJYAGzGCgB4BpOUGYNAEyRkYUQjQB8ACgBQcOXAhgiJJAC44AJWAZo-TgBo4Ab1nyz-YNgS5GMdQCMIERsARp9ps3LQIAtsHUkETFqDy95CyQMQOCaMPkAX3FpAEp1AAUoCF9CcjYtHSg9DkNHZ1c0cXFjTzgANwQoOCgKDMaiBEZ87V0DODKXNyq4AF5jBIBuWoB6abgAARgkAFpQFgwYVagspoBJbaZgBrR4INxsbDgAC1ZgWpaYXChSB6mE6WkdNCC4XiCAcSc-FGiAA7ghCKcKFRaAxmKxJEY4BYoGB1EiLFYbHZflBcMBDD5-OoAOQosAkwyRaJwEkAEVYYBQAEISXAEuyUnBZjgxHdPip4H8YAAhBD8ACMIIQ4MhZGhIXoTBYUERcBySCQIUyijUxn64vUInx7ISXJ5MBQLG422gAu+QuAQTF-AATNLZVDKIq4Sq1eT0cjLNZbEa8QS4ESArTyZSg1FSQzUSy4zwoAgwyaOWbuXNLdbWDsgA)